# deja dup, duplicity and google

Tags: deja-dup, google-drive, duplicity

I ran deja-dup to backup a directory to Google. It only worked partially, because authorization was lost before the job completed (in repeated attempts). I couldn't find a solution to that, so now I want to delete the partial backups and start fresh (with something other than deja-dup). It seems I need to use duplicity to do that properly, but I can't figure out how to find the values of the environment variables that would be needed in duplicity, and which (presumably) were used by deja-dup (as a front end for duplicity) for authentication to Google and for encryption. Google-drive shows up as a resource using "Files" [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS], so I imagine that info is stored somewhere on my machine. How do I find it?

Comment: If you just want to delete the files, open Google Drive in a browser or whatever and delete them. As far as backing up with duplicity, you may encounter the same problems, because deja-dup is kind of just a gui for duplicity.